# Identity element of a mathematical structure.

Tags: group-theory

I have just started learning about mathematical structures and I am confused about the concept of identity element. I know that for some structure, say $(S, \ast)$, the identity element is defined as $a\ast e = e \ast a = a$ where $e$ is the identity element $\forall\:a \in S$.

Now, if I define a structure as $(\mathbb N, \ast)$ where $\mathbb N$ is the set of natural numbers and $a \ast b = \gcd(a,b)$ for $a, b$ in $\Bbb N$, can I define an identity element $e$ such that $e$ is the product of all the elements in $\Bbb N$ ? The product of all the elements in $\Bbb N$ will be a unique number and it satisfies the property $a\ast e = e \ast a = a$. Please help me out.

Comment: It would be an infinite product??

Comment: But note for any natural number n gcd(n, n+1) =1

Comment: Yes, that would work. Note that the property $\forall a\in\mathbb{N}\ a*e=e*a=a$ is saying that for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$ the $\operatorname{gcd}(a,e)=a$. So, in particular, $\forall a\in\mathbb{N},\ a|e$. Of course, that element needs to be added to the structure, it doesn't currently belong to it.

Comment: @logarithm but the set of natural numbers in closed under multiplication. What do we do in that case?

Comment: That is up to you. You are the one defining some new structure.

Comment: Call $t = a*b*...$ We should then also add $t^2,t^3,t^4...$ right? since , once you add $t$, it could be combined with other elements. oops! isn't it mingling $\aleph_0$

Comment: Some binary operations don’t have an identity. Like real numbers with the operation of maximum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint.** $\gcd(0, a)=a=\gcd(a, 0)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{N}$.

On the other hand, "the product of all the elements contained in $\mathbb{N}$" is not an element of $\mathbb{N}$, and the identity of a structure must be contained in the structure (your definition is not precise enough: "the identity element is defined as **an element $e\in S$ such that** $a\ast e = e \ast a = a \:\forall\:a \in S$"). So no, your idea does not work.

Comment: but 0 $\notin$ $\Bbb N$

Comment: That very much depends on your upbringing.